# Why is this the answer?

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

Seen in a cryptic crossword (Metro, 9th May):

> Continental stagecoach industry [9]

The answer is

> DILIGENCE

but why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Europe, stagecoaches were referred to as

> DILIGENCE. [Check this Wikipedia link for more information.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagecoach#Continental_Europe)

The industry part might be a reference to its adjective form industrious, which is synonymous with diligent. Going back to the noun form leads us to

> DILIGENCE. [Check Google's list of synonyms for industrious here.](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=industrious%20synonym)